# Oracle Database Index Creation Problem For Big Table On OCI

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

On RDS:

1. I have a table "stats". It is ~400GB
2. I try to create an index for it: CREATE INDEX IDX_...
3. Index creations starts successfully.
4. It takes 10 hours long.

---

On OCI:

1. I have a table "stats". It is ~400GB
2. I try to create an index for it: CREATE INDEX IDX_...
3. Index creations starts successfully and continue for a while.
4. After 20 minutes, process disappeared(Except ssh(ServerAliveInterval 240)).
5. For ssh(ServerAliveInterval 240), it takes 10 hours to complete.

---

I tried it with 4 different client:

1. sql-developer -> didn’t work
2. java -> didn’t work
3. ssh -> didn't work
4. ssh(ServerAliveInterval 240) -> worked (when we keep alive the session, it worked.)

---

So my question is so clear. Why does it work with only ssh(ServerAliveInterval 240)? and is there a way to handle it on Java with some configuration? It should have a configuration because RDS solves it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related with EXPIRE_TIME in sqlnet.ora https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF209

it is 10(minutes) in OCI. Set as 0 and solved problem.